# deploying an artifact whit pom into a given repo in command line? (without pom edition and file-deploy)

Tags: java, maven

I have auto-generated java code I want to deploy in our maven repo. The generated code has a pom.xml without the repo info. I what to know if I can deploy the complete maven project in my repo without touching the pom. And by complete maven project, I mean not only the final jar using the file-deploy maven command.

The repo has security enabled and requires usr/pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. You need to add the server to the settings file as following:

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>my-server</id>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>pass</password>
  </server>
 </servers>
```

then I deploy using the following maven command (replacing `<url>` for the target repo):

```
mvn deploy -D"altDeploymentRepository=my-server::default::<url>"
```